# IVY Error: can't find the ivy.xml file

Tags: ant, ivy

I have the following ant and ivy files to set up my project. I want ivy to parse the file `D:/workspace/lib/apache/log4j/1.2.16/ivy.xml` to retrieve the log4j.jar.

But Ivy parses the file `D:/workspace/BuildStudy/ivy.xml`. And I don't have `D:/workspace/BuildStudy/ivy.xml file`. Does anybody have any idea about what's wrong with my ant and ivy setting files. Thanks.

build.xml file contains:

```
<project name="BuildStudy" default="main" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">    
    <target name="resolve" description="--> retrieve dependencies with ivy">        
      <ivy:retrieve/>
    </target>
</project>
```

ivysetting.xml file contains:

```
<ivysettings>
    <properties file="D:/workspace/BuildStudy/ivysettings-file.properties" />
    <caches  defaultCacheDir="${cache.dir}" />
    <property name="base.dir" value="D:/workspace/lib"/>
    <settings defaultResolver="CRMlocal"/>
    <resolvers>
        <filesystem name="CRMlocal">
            <ivy pattern="${base.dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"/>
            <artifact pattern="${base.dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]"/>
            <artifact pattern="${base.dir}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
        </filesystem>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

ivysettings-file.properties file contains:
cache.dir=D:/workspace/BuildStudy/.ivy_cache

Comment: where is the log4j.jar? In D:/workspace/lib/apache/log4j/1.2.16/? So  D:/workspace/lib/ is your repository. To retrieve something from a repository you need another ivy.xml for your project.

Comment: I have the log4j.jar and its ivy.xml file in D:/workspace/lib/apache/log4j/1.2.16/. Do you mean I should have an ivy.xml file in D:/workspace/lib/? The ivy.xml file is: <ivy-module version="1.0">
 <info organisation="apache" module="log4j" revision="1.2.16"/>
    <configurations >
        <conf name="default"/>
        <conf name="sources"/>
    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="log4j" type="jar" conf="default" />
        <artifact name="log4j-sources" type="source" ext="jar" conf="sources" />
    </publications>
</ivy-module>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ivy.xml](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile.html) files  describe an artifact and its dependencies.

An Ivy file is commonly used/present in two locations:

1. an repository (where it describes for example the log4j artifact)
2. a project (where it describes your project and lists ivy.xml as a dependency)

You already made the first step and created a local repository, that you [resolve](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/resolvers.html) with a filesystem resolver.

Now you need to declare an ivy.xml for your project like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=
                   "http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
<info organisation="myorg" module="BuildStudy"/>
<configurations>
    <conf name="compile" visibility="public" />
</configurations>
<publications>
   <artifact name="BuildStudy" type="jar"  conf="compile" ext="jar"/>
</publications>
<dependencies>>
    <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.14" conf="compile->*"/>
</ivy-module>
```

This describes your project with the following details:

- this project will build and provide an artifact BuildStudy.jar
- this project needs log4j to compile

Answer (score 6):

Add following property to your build.xml:

```
   <property name="ivy.dep.file" value="PATH TO ivy.xml" />
```